# How to use groupingBy on nested lists

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, groupingby

I am facing a tricky situation where I have to use groupingBy on an object which has nested lists. I tried few things with map(), flatmap(), toMap() but not able to come up with a solution and just going in circles. Any help here from the stream experts very much appreciated. I need to implement 2 methods in my OrdersAnalyzer class.
Here is how my objects look like:

```
public class Order {
  private final String id;
  private final Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();
  private final Customer customer;

  //getters, setters, equals, hashcode omitted for brevity
}
```

```
public class OrderLine {
  private final Product product;
  private final Integer quantity;

  //getters, setters, equals, hashcode omitted for brevity
}
```

```
public class Product {
  private final String name;
  private final BigDecimal price;

  //getters, setters, equals, hashcode omitted for brevity
}
```

```
public class OrdersAnalyzer {
    /**
     * Should return at most three most popular products. Most popular product is the product that have the most occurrences
     * in given orders (ignoring product quantity).
     * If two products have the same popularity, then products should be ordered by name
     *
     * @param orders orders stream
     * @return list with up to three most popular products
     */
    public List<Product> findThreeMostPopularProducts(Stream<Order> orders) {
      orders.forEach(order -> {
        order.getOrderLines().stream().collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(OrderLine::getProduct, *What to add here?* )
        );
      });
    }

    /**
     * Should return the most valuable customer, that is the customer that has the highest value of all placed orders.
     * If two customers have the same orders value, then any of them should be returned.
     *
     * @param orders orders stream
     * @return Optional of most valuable customer
     */
    public Optional<Customer> findMostValuableCustomer(Stream<Order> orders) {
      orders.collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer, *What to add here?*)
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `Collectors.groupingBy` ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Before deleting I had looked at your code snippet which worked fine :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**findThreeMostPopularProducts**

The API that you are looking to support needs you to create a frequency map of products to lookup as you find the `top-N`. In such cases `Collectors.counting()` would be a good `downstream` to make use of.

Note that it would provide you `Map<Product, Long> productFrequency` as a resultant, and then you would need to define a custom `Comparator<Map.Entry<Product, Long>>` aided with an additional check over the name comparison.

Furthermore, iterating over the entries of this map, while `sort`ing and `limit`ing to N elements shall get you closer to the answer that you are looking for.

---

**findMostValuableCustomer**

In this API, you are looking to compare the customers based on the highest values across their respective orders. So the grouping is sufficient with the default `toList` downstream.

It would aid you with `Map<Customer, List<Order>>`, amongst which you would need to find the entry with a `max` value of the price from all the orders of each customer.

So a comparator such as `Comparator.comparing(e -> findHighestValueOrder(e.getValue())`, where the `e.getValue()` is a `List<Order> customerOrders` would help you with the solution.

I would leave the implementation of `findHighestValueOrder` up to you, since if you know how to `map` and `flatMap`, you just need to find the `max` price amongst these orders or fallback to some default value such as `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: Thanks @Naman Your suggestions helped me. I was able to write the code.

Comment: this is _exactly_ what SO is about, imho.